# Angular *ngFor isn't populating values for <td>

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I've compared my code do a dozen or more other questions on SO and other search results, and I have no clue what I'm missing on this (I am new to angular, so that's probably part of it too). I can see that `orders` is being populated from `GetOrders()`, the `console.log` in `ngOnInit` shows the correct values. How do I properly implement the `*ngFor` in my html to show the data I want? I can see in the UI that the two sample rows are represented, so I know that the `*ngFor` is iterating both items in the array, but I don't know why it's not reading the data in the `<td>`'s. I'm using Angular 17 and TS 5.2.2. Here's everything I have:

all-orders.component.html:

```
<h1 id="tableLabel">All Orders</h1>

<p *ngIf="!orders"><em>Loading...</em></p>

<div *ngIf="orders">
  <table class='table table-striped' aria-labelledby="tableLabel">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Order Number</th>
        <th>Details</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let order of orders">
        <td>{{ order.OrderNumber }}</td>
        <td>{{ order.Details }}</td>
        <td>{{ order.CustName }}</td>
        <td>{{ order.CustEmail }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

all-orders.component.ts:

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { OrderService } from '../../services/order.service';
import { Order } from '../../models/order';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-all-orders',
  templateUrl: './all-orders.component.html'
})

export class AllOrdersComponent {
  public orders!: Order[];

  constructor(private orderService: OrderService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.orderService
      .GetOrders()
      .subscribe(result => {
        this.orders = result;
        console.log("this.orders: ", this.orders);
      });
  }
}
```

order.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/internal/Observable';
import { Order } from '../models/order';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class OrderService {
  private url = "Order"

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public GetOrders(): Observable<Order[]> {
    return this.http.get<Order[]>(`${environment.apiUrl}/${this.url}`);
  }
}
```

console data (expanding the values in the console shows the correct data, I have the screenshot collapsed for brevity):
[image: console data]

Comment: Your properties are in camelCase. Change them accordingly in the HTML template. E.g., order.orderNumber instead of order.OrderNumber.